# AngularJs conferindo variável em uma condicional pode dar problema sem especificar?

Tags: angularjs

**Exemplo simbolico:**

```
var num = undefined; // resultado será 3
var num = null; // resultado será 3
var num = 1; // resultado será 2
var num = 0; // resultado será 3

if (num) {
   resultado = 2;
} else {
   resultado = 3;
}
```

Porém muitas vezes no código observo que se aparecer 1 ou 0 poderá influenciar na resposta que estamos esperando..

Comment: Se a minha reposta o ajudou a compreender o tema coloque como resposta [aceite](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Se precisa de mais alguma explicação comente na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

**Vou seguir o seu exemplo:**

```
var num = undefined; // resultado será 3
var num = null; // resultado será 3
var num = 1; // resultado será 2
var num = 0; // resultado será 3

if (num) {
   resultado = 2;
} else {
   resultado = 3;
}
```

Em **Javascript** os valores `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `''`, `""` e `NaN` são considerados como `false`.

Todos os outros valores são considerados como `true`.

No seu caso, se `num` for `undefined`, `null` ou `0` o código dentro do bloco `if` não será executado e por isso o código `resultado = 3;`do bloco `else` será executado.

No caso de `num` ser `1` o valor de resultado será `2` pois entra dentro do bloco `if` e o código `resultado = 2;` é executado.

**Também deixo aqui um pequeno exemplo rápido para poder executar e verificar por si mesmo:**

```js
var valores = [undefined, null, 0, NaN, '', "", 1, 2, "0", [], "false", {}];

valores.forEach((valor) => {
  if(!valor){
    console.log("Quando o valor é `" + valor + "` corresponde a false");
  }
  else{
    console.log("Quando o valor é `" + valor + "` corresponde a true");
  }
  
})
```